# Google Maps API: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console

Tags: google-maps, authentication, limit, rate-limiting, quota

Doing some stress / load testing I got this message and figured out that I'm using the free version of the API and not the one available to us in our Google Premium Plan. We do have a clientId and a crypto key, but we are not sure on how to use them in the URL for proper authentication.

Could anyone please provide hints on such?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#premium-auth

Comment: As a Premium plan customer you can file a support case in your support portal and a dedicated team will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to apply a client ID and digital signature in web service requests you should follow this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/webservices/auth

If you need to authenticate Maps JavaScript API the documentations is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/clientside/auth

For load testing you can use a mock API instead of the real one. This way you won't consume your map credits.

Please read about load testing of Google Maps APIs here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/prelaunch-checklist#load_testing

Hope it helps!